# WebView in Flutter for Web is not loading Google Maps or others

Tags: google-maps, webview, flutter-web

Hei there,

I have the Problem that my WebView doesn't load. It only shows me a loading Screen.

I am using the flutter_webview_plugin in Flutter for Web.
I have no idea why its always loading. It does this always, with whatever Website I tried.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:website_aalen_by_night/widgets/info_card.dart';
import 'package:website_aalen_by_night/widgets/nav_bar.dart';

import 'package:flutter_webview_plugin/flutter_webview_plugin.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'AAlen by Night',
      theme: ThemeData.dark(),
      home: WebsiteAalenByNight(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class WebsiteAalenByNight extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  WebsiteState createState() => WebsiteState();
}

ScrollController controller = new ScrollController();

class WebsiteState extends State {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    FlutterWebviewPlugin().onHttpError.listen((WebViewHttpError item) {
      print("   WebView    onHttpError.code: ${item.code}");
    });

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(79, 79, 79, 1),
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Scrollbar(
            child: ListView(
              controller: controller,
              children: <Widget>[
                InfoCard(),
                Image(
                  image: AssetImage("lib/images/map.png"),
                  //height: height,
                  width: width,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
                InfoCard(),
                LimitedBox(
                  maxWidth: width,
                  maxHeight: height,
                  child: WebviewScaffold(
                    url: "https://www.google.com",
                    withZoom: false,
                    withLocalStorage: false,
                    withJavascript: true,
                    withLocalUrl: true,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          NavBar(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The goal of this is to implement a Map with Markers on the Screen. So I believed I can try a WebView but with that I did come to a stop soon.

Maybe there is a better Way to implement a Map (tried a few other Things like using a map plugin instead but I didn't find any which works for Flutter for Web).

> It is really important to get it working on Flutter for Web and NOT on
>   any other Platform!

Thanks for helping me....

Maybe in the Future I am able to answer such questions for others :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't think that https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_webview_plugin works in web since it uses native libraries.

HOWEVER, the great advantage of using a browser for your flutter app, is that you can use HTML and you don't need a webview there!

check this [example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/blob/master/examples/html_platform_view/lib/main.dart) of using a nested youtube player

```dart
void main() {
  ui.platformViewRegistry.registerViewFactory(
    'hello-world-html',
    (int viewId) => IFrameElement()
      ..width = '640'
      ..height = '360'
      ..src = 'https://www.youtube.com/embed/IyFZznAk69U'
      ..style.border = 'none'
  );
  runApp(Directionality(
    textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    child: SizedBox(
      width: 640,
      height: 360,
      child: HtmlElementView(viewType: 'hello-world-html'),
    ),
  ));
}
```

[source](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/32326)

Of course the communication with the content it's another history, since it's an iframe and in web browsers CORS is enabled it means you can't access the iframe from flutter, in the case of Google maps, they have an [URL api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) and pass your marker location there ;)

Comment: I am not able to import dart:html in flutter for web

Comment: I used the universal_html package instead, now its working :D thanks for helping

Comment: Hey dude, have you got any idea why I can't adjust the size of the widget the html window is being displayed in? It's just stretching the full size of the screen...

Comment: I think it might have something to do with being inside a SliverList... I haven't figured out a fix yet